# Intersection point of arcs

Tags: geometry

I have a straight line segment PQ between two points $P(x_0,y_0),Q(x_1,y_1).$

An arc of a circle is drawn whose tangents at P,Q  make angles $\alpha, \beta$  to PQ.

First: How to find the center  $(x0,y0)$ and radius of is circular arc $R$?

Second: How to find intersection(s) between two such arcs PQ and RS?

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:
Solve the line and circle as a system of equation.
Then check whether the solution is within the segment and arc.

Method 2:
Use parameter form for the line.
Then substitute it to the circle to solve it.
For two arc, use parameter form for the circle.
Then substitute it to the circle to solve it.
Finally, check whether the solution is within the segment and arc/arcs.

If two arcs are rotated ellipse. You can still write down points in the first arc in parameter form and substitute into equation of second arc to solve it.